# SSDT with Visual Studio Professional Edition vs Enterprise Edition

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sql-server, ssis

We need to setup SSDT for SSIS on SQLServer 2019. We would like to understand what is the difference if we go for Visual Studio Professional edition versus Visual Studio Enterprise edition. I see no specific advantage. We need to save cost. Community Version is not an option as it would be installed on production environment.

Comment: We finally decided on professional version. The SSDT topic even on Microsoft documentation is confusing. It would make sense to have dedicated SSDT portal plugged with SSIS. But I digress.